# Export SQL query based on custom field?

Tags: mysql, import, export, phpmyadmin

I'm operating on two WordPress sites and I need to export posts only with a specific custom field from one site and import into the other. I can't do a generic dump of the database because some data would be overridden.

My SQL query:

> SELECT * FROM wp_posts
>   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID
>   WHERE ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Color' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL );

Now I can export that into a .xml or .csv but I can't import that into the other site.

This is because the meta columns are appended to the row of the wp_posts. (Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/bjogBFYyoL)

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID WHERE ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'Color' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value IS NOT NULL );
```

That way it only gets the data in wp_posts, but still filters based on your criteria.

Comment: SELECT wp_posts.*  is the only change to the query, just so you know.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have a duplicate key problem so I can't import.

Comment: You can fix that by writing out all of the individual columns in the wp_posts table, except for the ID column. For example: SELECT wp_posts.post_author, wp_posts.post_date, wp_posts.post_date_gmt, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_title, etc, etc...